# Extracting excel data after unzipping using rubyzip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubyzip, roo

I'm trying to get spreadsheet data from zipped .xlsx files. I'm using `rubyzip` to access the contents of the zipfile

```
Zip::File.open(file_path) do |zip_file|
   zip_file.each do |entry|
     *process entry*
   end
end
```

My problem is that rubyzip gives a `Zip::Entry` object, which, I cant get to work with gems like `roo` or `creek`.

I've done something similar, but with .csv file. This was as simple as `CSV.parse(entry.get_input_stream.read)`. However, that just gives me a string of encoded gibberish when using it on an .xlsx file.

I've looked around and the closest answer I got was temporarily extracting the files, but I want to avoid doing this since the files can get pretty large.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need to do is convert the stream into an `IO` object that `Roo` can understand.

To determine if the object passed to `Roo::Spreadsheet.open` is a "stream" `Roo` uses the following method:

```
 def is_stream?(filename_or_stream)
    filename_or_stream.respond_to?(:seek)
  end
```

Since a `Zip::InputStream` does not respond to `seek` you cannot use this object directly. To get around this we simply need an object that does respond to `seek` (like a [`StringIO`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html))

We can just `read` the input stream into the `StringIO` directly:

```
stream = StringIO.new(entry.get_input_stream.read)
```

Or the `Zip` library also provides a method to copy a `Zip::InputStream` to another `IO` object through the [`IOExtras`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyzip/rubyzip/Zip/IOExtras#copy_stream-class_method) module, which I think reads fairly nicely as well.

Knowing all of the above we can implement as follows:

```
Zip::File.open(file_path) do |zip_file|
   zip_file.each do |entry|
     # make sure Roo can handle the file (at least based on the extension)
     ext = File.extname(entry.name)&.to_sym 
     next unless Roo::CLASS_FOR_EXTENSION[ext]
     # stream = StringIO.new(entry.get_input_stream.read)
     ::Zip::IOExtras.copy_stream(stream = StringIO.new, entry.get_input_stream)
     spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(stream, extension: ext)
     # process file
   end
end
```